# How to use Redis and Redis-Sentinel without saving passwords in clear-text?

Tags: security, redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel, redis-server

I use Redis 6.2 services on different servers, and each one of them has a Redis Sentinel instance.

For each Redis instance, I have a `redis.conf` that stores:

1. The password that clients and Sentinel use to authenticate as `requirepass <password>`

For each Sentinel instance, I have a `sentinel.conf` that stores:

2. The password Sentinel uses to authenticate with the Redis services as `sentinel auth-pass <master-name> <password>`
3. The password clients use to authenticate with the Sentinel service as `requirepass <password>`
4. The password Sentinel uses to authenticate with other Sentinels as `sentinel sentinel-pass <password>`

Now, I'm trying to eliminate clear text passwords.

By using ACL, I'm able to store the password hashed in the service and remove (1) from redis.conf.

I might be able to eliminate (3) by using ACL for the Sentinel.

However, what are my options if I want to keep the passwords, don't want to store them in the .conf files (or in env. variables), especially the Redis master password in sentinel.conf (2)?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running with passwords, If I'm adding requirepass to Redis, my sentinels are saying master is down only.